# How do I talk (in-game) with a GM?

Tags: diablo-iii, technical-issues

I got some issues in Diablo-3 and want to talk to a GM. There is a way to talk with them in-game? I only found the "Open a Ticket" option in the site.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no "GM"s, that is very much MMO terminology.

Since the game does not require a monthly fee, the support system is done by traditional support staff through conventional e-mail and telephone means.